# ngClass and ngStyle directive onclick element color needs to change in angular?

Tags: css, angular, ng-class, ng-style

Hi every one I have created stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-giypgb?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html for reference, I have used expansion panel to exapand the content, based on click the element the expansion happening in the stackblitz, for example if we click **All** element on top the **all** content will gets exapand, if we click **B** element the **B** content will gets expand.

What I exactly looking is I want to use **ngstyle or ngclass** in top loop of **{{tab}}**, if we click **All** tag it should be change into **green color** and again if click same **All** tag it's should change into **red color**, if we click **B** tag it should be change into **green color** again if click same **B** tag it's should change into **red color** like toggle.

if **panelstate = false** the tag should be in red color and if it is **true** it's need to change green color

**panel open state:-**

```
panelOpenState = false;
```

**Top ngfor loop;-**

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div *ngFor="let tab of getTablist();"> <p  (click)='clickOntab(tab)' [ngStyle]="{'color':panelOpenState === 'true' ? 'green' : 'red' }">{{tab}}</p></div>
</div>
```

**Ts File**

```
panelOpenState = false;
  public tabType: string = "";
    
      clickOntab(tab) {
        if (this.tabType != "" && this.tabType === tab) {
          this.panelOpenState = false;
          this.tabType = "";
        } else {
          this.panelOpenState = true;
          this.tabType = tab;
        }
      }
    
      getTablist() {
        const tabList = this.cricketList.map(list => list.alphabet);
        return ["All"].concat(tabList);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using **`ngClass`** like shown below,

```
[ngClass]="(panelOpenState===true)?'greenClass':'redClass'"
```

As of now **`ngClass`** of all tabs are binded to single property **`panelOpenState`**, so all are changing colors altogether but you should store the open or closed state of each tab separately in some array. Such that only the tab i.e opened is green in color and vice-versa.

Refer this working example [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-lcef1t?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best readable soultion would be this:

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div *ngFor="let tab of getTablist();">
        <p (click)='clickOntab(tab)' [class.redClass]="!panelOpenState" [class.greenClass]="panelOpenState">
            {{tab}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-efsckm?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

A simple approach to add an array with the tabs name

```
  tab = ["ALL", "A", "B", "C"];
  panelOpenState = "";
```

and make panelOpenState to store the open tab name.

Secondly update the template file as follows:

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div *ngFor="let tab of getTablist();">
        <p (click)='clickOntab(tab)'
            [ngStyle]="{'color':panelOpenState === tab ? 'green' : 'red' }">{{tab}}</p>
    </div>
```

ngStyle will trigger when the tab name is equal to the panelOpenState and this will do the trick.